# I'm displaying an array of string representations of elements. How can I highlight similar html tags in an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to allow users to enter a URL into an input, display the source of the page that they searched for, and highlight elements that are alike when they click them.

**What I'm doing:**

I am able to return and display the website's source using an express server. I then parse the source into an array of string representations of the html tags, and display them by mapping through the array and displaying them in an "ElementText" component.

**The issues:**

I am unable to parse the html string representations into the elements. I can do this for most of them with the hacky "getNodeType" method I've made, but this will not work for certain types of elements (html, head, body, etc) because these types of elements cannot be contained within a div.

I'm also struggling with the highlight functionality - it's current state is that it will highlight the whole element (including the element's content) and will not highlight the closing tag. How would I go about highlighting just the opening and closing tags? I've heard that regexs are not ideal for parsing html, and I've had no luck with the DOMParser.

**Simply Put:**

1: How can I highlight the opening and closing tags of alike elements?

2: How can I parse a string representation of an element into an actual html element?

My components are as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import UserInput from './UserInput';
import axios from 'axios';
import ElementText from './ElementText';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedTag: null,
      inputValue: '',
      sourceContent: '',
    }
  }

  noHttpInUrl(url){
    url.split('').splice(0,4).join('') !== 'http';
  }

  getPageSource(){
    if (this.noHttpInUrl) this.state.inputValue = `http://${this.state.inputValue}`;
    axios.post('/url', {
      params: {
        inputValue: this.state.inputValue,
      },
    }).then(res => {
      this.setState({sourceContent: this.extractHtmlTags(res.data)});
    });
}

extractHtmlTags(source){
  var html = source;
  var arr = html.split(/></g);

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].substring(0, 1) != '<'){
      arr[i] = '<' + arr[i];
    }
    if(arr[i].slice(-1) != '>'){
      arr[i] = arr[i] + '>';
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.getPageSource();
}

handleElementClick(element) {
  const nodeType = this.getNodeType(element);
  this.setState({ selectedTag: nodeType });
}

getNodeType(element) {
  const temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = element;
  if (temp.firstChild) return temp.firstChild.nodeName;
  else return null;
}

  render() {
    let websiteSource;
    if(this.state.sourceContent) {
      websiteSource = this.state.sourceContent.map((element, index) => {
        console.log(element);
        let selected = false;
        if (this.getNodeType(element) === this.state.selectedTag) selected = true;
        return (
          <ElementText
            key={index}
            text={element}
            selected={selected}
            onClick={() => this.handleElementClick(element)}
          />
        )
      });
    } else {
      websiteSource = null;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          id="url-input"
          type="text"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })} />
        <button id="submit" onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
        <div id="content">
          { websiteSource }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

ElementText Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

class ElementText extends Component {
  render() {
    const { text, onClick, selected } = this.props;
    const selectedStyle = {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    };
    if (selected) return <span onClick={onClick} style={selectedStyle}>{text}</span>;
    else return  <span onClick={onClick}>{text}</span>;
  }
}

export default ElementText;
```

Apologies if this question is too long-winded. Any help is very much appreciated, I've spent lots of time researching this to no avail. Pretty new to this. Thanks very much!